# Struggling with Arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

[This is an image of the requirements that I need to follow and include](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6E1x.png)

I am having trouble with everything not really good with arrays. 
This is what I have so far
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks
The part that I am mostly struggling would be step 2.
As for step 3 and 4, I have part of the requirement I just need to bring back the name and ID number as well with the highest and lowest score.

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class Final project

    {
      public static void main(String args[])
      {

     Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] studentID = new int [5];

    String[] studentName = new String [5];

    int [] studentScore = new int [5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)

     { 

      System.out.println("Student Number " + (i+1) + "");

    System.out.println("Student ID Number: ");

    studentID [i] = console.nextInt();

    System.out.println(" Student Name: " + console.nextLine()+"");

     studentName [i] = console.nextLine();

     System.out.println("Grade: ");

      studentScore [i] = console.nextInt();

     }

    int max = printLowest(studentScore);

    System.out.println("Highest score is: "+max);

    int min = printHighest(studentScore);

     System.out.println("Lowest score is: "+min);

    }


     public static int printLowest(int[] inputArray){ 

     int maxValue = inputArray[0]; 

     for(int i=1;i < inputArray.length;i++){ 

     if(inputArray[i] > maxValue){ 

      maxValue = inputArray[i]; 

      } 

     } 

     return maxValue; 

    }

     public static int printHighest(int[] inputArray){ 

    int minValue = inputArray[0]; 

     for(int i=1;i<inputArray.length;i++){ 

     if(inputArray[i] < minValue){ 

      minValue = inputArray[i]; 

     } 

      } 

      return minValue; 

    } 

    }
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Poor title. Summarize the core of your issue rather than a generic topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can try something like this:
public static void printRoster()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)

     { 
java.util.Arrays.sort(studentid);
java.util.Arrays.sort(studentName );
java.util.Arrays.sort(studentScore);
 }
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
 System.out.println(studentid[i] + " " + studentName [i] + " " + studentScore 
}
}
```

Comment: I was able to compile it and add it to the overall program but I can't seem to get it to go into the main string to have it execute it, do you think you would be able to help me with that as well?

Comment: You need to call it from main method as printRoster(); , since your method is static so no need to create object for it.

Comment: I was able to add it like you instructed me to and for the most part it works it just seems to be having a problem with the student score

Comment: additionally i had to remove the [i] because it was't compiling with it, do you think that that might be the problem as to why it is not working?